# {{block type="core/template" column_count="4" category_id="50" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}} is not working in magento2

Tags: categories, magento2

I am new to **magento2**. I want to show a particular category products in my home page. I am using this code:

```
{{block type="core/template" column_count="4" category_id="50" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But it's not working.

Thanks in advance,
rani

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code like this :

```
{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" category_id="50" name="home.products.list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to display product of particular category. Just add line of code in pages.**

```
 {{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct"
 name="category.products.list" as="product_list" category_id="51"
 template="product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to add the products on home then follow the few steps.

1. Edit your home page -> click on Insert Widget-> select catalog product list-> 
   Select category in Conditions

[image]